# build table column group from column definition(like agGrid Column Groups)

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

i have below column definition..expecting a javascript function that will take the columnDefinition as input and output the column tree with proper colspan. trying to achieve the agGrid column group (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-groups/) with my own javascript function

```
let columnDefinition = [
  {
    headerName: "Audit Group",
    children: [
      {
        headerName: "Audit Area Name"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Audit Area Description"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    headerName: "GG",
    children: [
      {
        headerName: "Status"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    headerName: "Logo",
    children: [
      {
        headerName: "2023",
        children: [
          {
            headerName: "Logo Upload"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

expecting the below output

```
[
[{headerName:'Audit Group', colspan:2},{headerName:'GG',colspan:1},{headerName:'Logo',colspan:1}],
[{headerName:'', colspan:2},{headerName:'',colspan:1},{headerName:'2023',colspan:1}],
[{headerName:'Audit Area Name',colspan:1},{headerName:'Audit Area Description',colspan:1},{headerName:'Status',colspan:1},{headerName:'Logo Upload',colspan:1}]
]
```

what i tried so far https://codesandbox.io/s/long-leaf-8pez21

unable to get the Column Groups like the agGrid..